# How does a frame of reference work in relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, observers, twin-paradox

I am struggling to understand what frame of reference means in relativity.
Imagine the twin scenario. Twin A is at rest, while twin B travels somewhere and back at near the speed of light. If one takes as a frame of reference the one where twin A is at rest, then time goes slowly for Twin B, thus making it so that when B returns, A is older. 
Now I get really confused, if I take twin B's rest frame as the frame of reference, then he was stationary all the time, and A was moving at close to the speed of light, thus B will be older than A.
What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: B is the only one that accelerates. Look up the solution to the twin paradox

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the classical twin paradox resolved?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2554/)