# Twin paradox in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, time, reference-frames, observers

The Twin Paradox involves 2 observers, usually twins. Let them be named *A* and *B*. *A* remains at rest in the same reference frame as Earth while *B* is in a separate reference frame moving at velocity *v*, close to the speed of light, from *A*. After a certain amount of time, *B* switches reference frames to another which moves at the same speed but in the opposite direction, towards *A*.

Generally, we would say that due to time dilation, *B* would have aged less than *A*. However, consider the case where *B* is stationary and that the Earth together with *A* are moving similarly and changing reference frames. In this case, A would have aged less than B.

These 2 cases should both be equally valid through the observations of *A* and *B*. However, this would cause a contradiction in how they have experienced time.

Please enlighten me on how this is resolved where *A* ages more than *B*. I would like to find out if I have made any misconceptions in my understanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the classical twin paradox resolved?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2554/)

Comment: This question has been asked [many, many times before](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=twin%20paradox).

Comment: Whenever you want to ask for the resolution of an incredibly famous physics question, please consider that it has probably already been asked before. Also, as JohnRennie has generously pointed out for you via a link, *this site has a search box*. Please use it.