# From which reference frame is the time dilation factor measured?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, time-dilation

I do not know much physics so please try to answer as simply as possible. I am probably confused but I recently learned that in Special Relativity (you can tell that I don't know much physics), the faster an object is moving, the more time slows down for that object. I also learnt that it is slowed down by a factor $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$.

However, how is the velocity measured? From my reference frame, I never move. If I walked away from someone, presumably time would slow down ever so slightly for me compared to the other person. However, in my reference frame, I just see the other person moving away from me. Which person does time slow down for and why?

Comment: If you fly past me in a rocket then your measure of time will appear to me to have slowed down. But for you, on your rocket, time will feel like it's passing normally. Similarly, from *your* point of view, *my* measure of time will appear to be slower. So what happens when we come back together and compare time? Well this is the so-called [twin paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox). Addressed many times on this site [(e.g.)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/how-is-the-classical-twin-paradox-resolved).

Comment: You might want to see my recent very elementary answer to essentially the same question at http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240124/time-dilation-confusion/240223#240223 .

Comment: The absolute value of the velocity of the movement would be the same from both observer systems. That's part of the facts of relativity: $|{v_{AB}}|=|{v_{BA}}|$. There may be a disagreement about the direction (we usually chose the coordinate systems parallel, so that the two velocities have opposite direction). This leads to exactly the same time dilation factor.